# How do you hang something on sheetrock where there is a plastic stud?

Tags: drywall, anchor

When hanging an L bracket, I ran a test drill to see if there was a stud.  I hit what I thought was the stud but it turns out to be a plastic stud.  How do I anchor through the sheetrock?  My screw will not pierce the plastic stud.

Comment: I have never used plastic studs. Are you sure it is a plastic stud. If there is wiring in the wall less than 1-1/4" from the surface of the stud metal plates are required to protect the wiring. I would be concerned that you are drilling into a conduit or water pipe.

Comment: What color plastic? Black suggests abs plumbing pipe; some electrical stuff is gray. I too have never experienced plastic studs, but I don't know where in the world you are, either.

Answer (score 2):

How old is the building you are working in? Only a very new one might have (ecostud.com/product_details.html ) plastic framing studs. More likley you have drilled into a plastic pipe. If your water is on and you haven't noticed a leak you have drilled into a drain line or a plumbing vent stack. If it was my house I would cut a small opening in sheet rock at that very same location to verify what you have drilled into and if it is in fact a pipe open the wall enough to repair the hole in the pipe.

Please let us know what you find. 
And if it is a stud made of plastic explain why a screw would not pierce it.  Studs are after all supposed to be accepting of dry wall screws regardless of what they are made of.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.  As it turns out, it was a metal stud which explains the flex I felt when trying to secure the screw.  I had cleaned out the screw hole with compressed air prior to posting my question but there was still sheetrock dust that made the stud appear white.  I knew it wasn't an electrical or water line so I checked to see if there was such a thing as a plastic stud - and there is.  Used for nonload bearing interior walls or possibly for rocking a concrete block basement. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Metal studs come in different gauges heavy gauge studs can be resistant to standard screws. The self drilling screws work good on them. But for just mounting a L bracket or two I would drill a pilot hole and then attach with normal screw.